# Not able to deploy ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I am trying to implement an iPad application with asp.net MVC 3 and jQuery Mobile.
Can any one help me to figure it out why I can not deploy my application?

My server : Windows 2008 R2 Standard 64 Bit 
IIS : 7.5
Application pool : ASP.NET v4.0

MvcDiagnositics Info as below

---

Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Diagnostics Information

This page is designed to help diagnose common errors related to mismatched or conflicting ASP.NET MVC binaries.

If a known issue is identified, it will be displayed below in red text.
For questions or problems with ASP.NET MVC or this utility, please visit the ASP.NET MVC forums at http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx.

**Environment Information**

**Operating system:** Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0

**.NET Framework version:** 4.0.30319.225 (32-bit) **<----- This should be 64-bit???**

**Web server:** Microsoft-IIS/7.5

**Integrated pipeline:** False

**Worker process:** w3wp.exe

**AppDomain:** Homogenous = True, FullTrust = True

**ASP.NET MVC Assembly Information (System.Web.Mvc.dll)**

Assembly version: Unknown version (3.0.20105.0)

Full name: System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Code base: file:///F:/Projects/Mobile/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL

Deployment: bin-deployed

ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly Information (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll)

An ASP.NET MVC Futures assembly has not been loaded into this application. A download for this

version of ASP.NET MVC Futures is not available. Pre-release versions of the MVC Futures assembly

are no longer available once that version of ASP.NET MVC has gone RTM.

All Loaded Assemblies

48 assemblies are loaded.

•App_global.asax.ur2ey1at, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null [ ver = n/a, GAC = False ]

•App_Web_umu0ymeo, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null [ ver = n/a, GAC = False ]

•EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.1.10331.0, GAC = False ]

•FiftyOne.Foundation, Version=2.0.6.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e0b3a8da0bbce49c [ ver = 2.0.6.2, GAC = False ]

•Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 10.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•Mobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null [ ver = 1.0.0.0, GAC = False ]

•mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.225, GAC = True ]

•SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Runtime.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.206, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.206, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 3.0.20105.0, GAC = False ]

•System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 1.0.20105.407, GAC = False ]

•System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

•System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [ ver = 4.0.30319.1, GAC = True ]

Diagnostics version: Friday, December 10, 2010 (v11)

### Report generated on: Monday, April 16, 2012 10:08:33 AM

And my Global.asax Info as below

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name

"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters

new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults

);

---

My Web.config info as below

---

When I test it from my local machine I am able to see this Default page as below

Welcome to the Mobile Home Page

Here's some information about the requesting device:

•Screen Width: 640

•Screen Height: 480

•LayoutEngine: Trident

See MSDN for details of Request.Browser properties.

See 51Degrees.mobi for user guide.

See 51Degrees.mobi Device Data for details of other data properties and to get weekly data updates.

---

The requesting device isn't a mobile. The page must have been requested directly.

### Try accessing the web site from a mobile device, or a mobile device emulator. A list of popular mobile emulators can be found here.

I have tried to install the aspnet_regiis.exe -i on the server

and I get this error as below

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i Start installing 
ASP.NET (4.0.30319). ................ Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319). Setup has detected some errors during the operation. For details, please read th e setup log file C:\Users\ADMINI~1.HIS\AppData\Local\Temp\2\ASPNETSetup_00009.log

---

**Is that because the aspnet_regiis.net for 64-bit is not installed correctly?

I have been trying to deploy me application on ther server for 3 days but I didn't find any luck.

Please, Help me to find out the issue.

Thank you very much in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

try this

install the mvc framework on your server and publish your website to a folder and copy that folder to your server.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Right click “Sites”
3. Hit “Add Web Site…”
4. Enter site name
5. Hit the “Select…” button to chose an application pool
6. Chose “ASP.NET v4.0” (pipleline mode: integrated)
7. In the “Content Directory” group enter/browse path to the website deployment folder(where you copied it to your server)
8. Hit the “Test Settings…” button to verify that the credentials meet the requirements
9. In the “Binding” group enter type, IP address, port and host name
10. Select the new website in the treeview on the left side
11. Double click the “Authentication” icon in the feature view (middle view)
12. In the new view select the “Anonymous Authentication” row
13. Click “Edit…” in the actions panel (on the right side)
14. In the popup view select the “Application Pool Identity” radio button, hit OK
15. OPTIONAL: Recycle the app pool and restart the website